# Rails 3 Routing Error - "No Route Matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm following along with the O'Reilly Rails book, but it's created for Rails 2, so I think that's where the error lies.

In app/views/entries/sign_in.html.erb:

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello <%=h @name %> </title> </head>
<body>
<h1> Hello <%=h @name %></h1>

<%= form_tag :action => 'sign_in' do %>
   <p>Enter your name:
   <%= text_field_tag 'visitor_name', @name %> </p>
   <%= submit_tag 'Sign in' %>
   <% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

And in app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:

```
  class EntriesController < ApplicationController
     def sign_in
        @name = params[:visitor_name]
     end

   end
```

When I click the 'Sign In' button, it takes me to a page that says:

Routing Error

No route matches "/entries/sign_in"

I would post my routes.rb file, but it seems that it's all commented out except for this line:

get "entries/sign_in"

This file seems different than the one they're referencing in the book, so that's why I believe this to be the problem.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 router has changed a lot. See this blog post:
http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/

What you want to do might be:

```
resources :entries do
  collection do
    post :sign_in
  end
end
```

This adds an action on the whole collection (/entries/sign_in) of entries (in contrast to #member, which would be accessed via /entries/:id/sign_in).
Though I'm not sure why you'd want to sign in someone in the entries resource. You might create a seperate controller for that.

Answer (score 5):

If you're learning Rails, you'd find it a lot easier to be using the same version of Rails as the book you're learning it from. Either learn in Rails 2 and upgrade to 3 later, or get a new book.

There are a lot of differences between Rails 2 and 3, so you're going to be spending all your time getting confused with things like this.